# wordpress exclude directory

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a simple problem but that i not found a solution online: i need to exclude fisical directory from a test webserver on my pc called "stopdebiti2012b" that contain wordpress core,in the wp-content/themes/ i have the theme "stopdebiti" and i have created a directory named "blog/" i need to exclude that from mod_rewrite but nothing is happened.

I have used all of common solution explains on internet..but nothing it happened?

How can i solve this?

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /stopdebiti2012b/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /stopdebiti2012b/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   # END WordPress
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|blog/.*)$
```

after

```
RewriteBase /stopdebiti2012b/
```